# what is wrong here using when-clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have scenario like below:

```
 val df = // dataset have columns like "col", "col_a",  "col_b".
  val  type = "" //dynamicLLT passed by user 
 //based on this, need to add one more colum "value" based "col" value.


 val valueDs =  df
        .withColumn("type", lit(type).cast(StringType))
         .withColumn("value", 
                 when(col("cal").equalTo(lit("A_B")),concat_ws("_",col("col_a"), col("col_b"))).
                 when(col("cal").equalTo(lit("A")),concat(col("col_a")))
                );
```

Need to select  other columns based on "type" and populate "value" column appropriately.

But when I run """col("cal"). == ("A") """ if fails due to field "col_b" not available  .

So what is wrong here ? Why it looking for "col_b" which is not there.
How to fix this when-clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below.

```
val valueDs =  df
        .withColumn("type", lit(type).cast(StringType))
         .withColumn("value", 
                 when((col("cal") === "A_B"),concat_ws("_",col("col_a"), col("col_b"))).
                 when((col("cal") === "A"),concat(col("col_a")))
                .otherwise("null")
         );
```

Comment: ok, It will not look for col("col_b").. first your query will be parsed, analyzed & then executed. In analysis phase your query has some additional columns which your dataframe don't have. here it will throw an exception - org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`col_b`' given input columns : [...]

when clause will be rewritten like - CASE WHEN (cal = A_B) THEN concat_ws(_, col_a, col_b) WHEN (cal = A) THEN concat(col_a) END